# Having trouble stacking items within a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to stack two items within a div and having trouble doing so. My ideal result is to have three columns (essentially) with blocks 1 and 2 in the first column, and blocks 3 and 4 in the second and third columns (as in my example).

This is what I am getting now:

[image]

This is what I would like to get:

[image]

This is my code:

```css
#Blocks {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 25px solid #ff6a00;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 25px;
}

#StackedBlocks {
  display: inline-block;
  /*What else should go here?*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
  <title>Site</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="Blocks" class="all">
    <div id="StackedBlocks">
      block 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="Blocks" class="all">
    <div id="StackedBlocks">
      block 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="Blocks" class="all">
    block 3
  </div>
  <div id="Blocks" class="all">
    block 4
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions you can make!

UPDATED CODE:

```css
.all{
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 25px solid #ff6a00;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 25px;
  float: left;
}

#StackedBlocks {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
    <title>Site</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="StackedBlocks">
        <div id="block1" class="all">
            block 1
    </div>
    <div id="block2" class="all">
            block 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="block3" class="all">
        block 3
    </div>
    <div id="block4" class="all">
        block 4
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not re-use `id` attributes, they are supposed to be unique.

Comment: What @chazsolo said. Use multiple classes if needed instead. IDs should always be unique. I possible, rather than messing with the CSS, I would change the HTML so that blocks 1 and 2 are in the same div. This would make it much easier to solve the problem. Because atm, the inner divs are redundant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display:flex.`

And don't re-use `id`

```css
body
{
  display:flex;
}

.Blocks {
   flex:1;
   border:1px solid black;
}

.StackedBlocks {
    height: 150px;
    border: 25px solid #ff6a00;
    margin:10px;
    /*What else should go here?*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
    <title>Site</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="Blocks" class="all">
        <div class="StackedBlocks">
            block 1
        </div>
        <div class="StackedBlocks">
            block 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Blocks" class="all">
      <div class="StackedBlocks" class="all">
          block 3
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="Blocks" class="all">
      <div class="StackedBlocks" class="all">
          block 4
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make a suggestion based on my new code please? I don't think flex does what I want.

Comment: if you want to do three columns you have to set up your columns with a class and then apply css on columns. Else, if you keep your html, you will not work with colums and you will be force to use other css layout, like float.

Comment: ok there is other solution, set `.all {display:inline-block} ` and `#StackedBlocks .all { display :block}`. In fact this is Happysmithers's response

Comment: That does stack 1 and 2, thank you. But, then 3 and 4 are not at the top of the page, they sit in line with 2. Also, it looks like the Blockswrapper class takes up 1/3 of the screen but the blocks within it are maybe 1/2 of that, which is not correct.

Comment: use `vertical-align :top`

Comment: Great! Now the only problem is that blocks 1 and 2 take up 25% of the div they are in which takes up 25% of the screen. How do I get them to use the full width of their div?

Comment: try something like this : `#StackedBlocks .all { width :auto}`

Answer (score 0):

What about just wrapping the first two in another DIV?

```css
.Blocks {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid #ff6a00;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 25px;
}
.Blockswrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="Blockswrapper">
  <div class="Blocks" class="all">
    <div class="StackedBlocks">
      block 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Blocks" class="all">
    <div class="StackedBlocks">
      block 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="Blocks" class="all">
  block 3
</div>
<div class="Blocks" class="all">
  block 4
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't quite give the result OP is looking for, although the suggestion of wrapping is valid.

Comment: I've tried wrapping, please see updated code, but how do I get 1 and 2 to stack in the same amount of room as 3 and 4 have in the second and third columns?

Answer (score 0):

Dont reuse IDs, rather style on the classes. I think the best way is to explain it with a real example from css-tricks:

> Maybe a good analogy here is bar codes and serial numbers. Take an iPod in a store. On the packaging will be a bar code. This tells the store what the product is, so when it is scanned, the system knows exactly what the product is and what it costs. It might even be able to know what color it is or where it was kept in the store. All iPod of this same type have the exact same bar code on them.
>
> The iPod will also have a serial number on it which is absolutely unique to any other iPod (or any other device) in the world. The serial number doesn't know the price. It could, but for the store this wouldn't be a very efficient way to store and use that data. Much easier to use the barcode, so that for example, if the price changed, you could just change the price for that bar code and not every individual serial number in your system.
>
> This is much like `ID's` and `Classes`. Information that is reusable should be kept in a `class` and information that is totally unique should be kept in an `ID`.

Besides this I would recommend to use `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block` if you want to place the elementsnext to each other. Then the css would look like this:

```
.all {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 25px solid #ff6a00;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 25px;
  float: left;
}
```

---

#### Edit

Regarding the topic of **grids**, I can recommend this css-tricks article and the bootstrap grid system if you want to learn more about this:

- https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/
- http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: This does not create the desired result.

Comment: Despite float's ability to "place elements next to each other", I don't think it's a useful recommendation for layout. There are many better methods in CSS that do not come with float's baggage.

Comment: Float doesn't seem to do it. Above is my new code with unique IDs. How do I get 1 and 2 to stack in the first column, and 3 and 4 to take up the same amount of space in the second and third column?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use flexboxes to create columns, they always come out perfectly sized. And like others suggested, I would put the first two boxes in a single div element. Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvWYyy

HTML:

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="block">Block 1</div>
    <div class="block">Block 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="block">Block 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="block">Block 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.columns {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
}

.block {
  height: 300px;
  border: 25px solid #ff6a00;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

### Alternate answer

You can use [column-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/column-count) on a `.wrapper` `div` to stack the inner `div` elements vertically

This can be further adjusted for better responsiveness depending on the content.

Working example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0
}

.Blocks {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 25px solid #ff6a00;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  column-count: 3
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="Blocks">
    block 1
  </div>
  <div class="Blocks">
    block 2
  </div>
  <div class="Blocks">
    block 3
  </div>
  <div class="Blocks">
    block 4
  </div>
  <div class="Blocks">
    block 5
  </div>
  <div class="Blocks">
    block 6
  </div>
  <div class="Blocks">
    block 7
  </div>
  <div class="Blocks">
    block 8
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems like it's on the right track but I only want 1 and 2 to be stacked, not  all of them. How do I apply it to only the first two? It seems like even when I did it to only the div where there are the first two, it applied it to all four.